# Hide next button from code behind in asp.net in wizard control

Tags: c#, asp.net, animation, wizard

I have an asp.net page having a wizard control. I wanted to make visible false Next Button when other than Admin logged in (say dealer, subdealer log in). How to make it invisible or to change its text? I tried this line to make it in visible:

> > ((Button)Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton")).Visible = false;

HTML is:

```
   <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="False" Width="90%" StepPreviousButtonText=""
            StepPreviousButtonType="Image" 
            onfinishbuttonclick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" 
            onnextbuttonclick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
            <NavigationStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                     //Some design 
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                     //Some design
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>

            <StartNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext"    

                Text="Next" />
            </StartNavigationTemplate>
      <FinishNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="Finish" />
        </FinishNavigationTemplate>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

but sounds nothing there. What have I to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
((Button)Wizard1.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton")).Visible = false;
```

I had replace `StepNavigationTemplateContainerID` with `StartNavigationTemplateContainerID` as you need to find from Start Naveigation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the **StartNextButton** just set `StartNextButtonType` to "Link" and `StartNextButtonText` to Empty. That should be the most easy way